# GET parameters over HTTPS

Tags: tls

How are the GET parameters passed?

example

I Understand the HTTP Connection is started by browser as below

```
1) Connect with TCP port 80
2) after connection, pass the following over the connection
    GET /?parameter=secure_data
3) Receive the data content (Could be text, html, image etc)
4) Display the data
```

Is this the same kind of process followed by the browser for HTTPS?

```
1) Connect with TCP port 443
2) establish a secure connections
3) after secure connection, pass the following over the connection
    GET /?parameter=secure_data
4) Receive the data content (Could be text, html, image etc)
5) Display the data
```

If it is then the parameters are transferred securely over TLS.

I am not developing the webapp but my client is passing the parameters over GET request parameters and I have a doubt over how this is handled by TLS over HTTPS.

I don't care about security issue of logging the request URI in the Browser History or request URI logged by the server.

I am mainly interested in knowing if the parameters are passed by HTTPS over TLS or not.

Comment: The process is the same, it's just the message is encrypted so I can't see your traffic.

Comment: If you wish to see proof of this, have a search for SSLKEYLOGFILE and Wireshark. Hope it helps.

Comment: from what I've read the get/post vars are passed securely, but the URL itself is not.   So destination can be read from a standard DNS server, but not the query values.

Comment: So GET /path is passed over SECURE connection and will not be accessible to anyone other than the browser or the intended server, right? i.e. MitM attack will not be possible.

Comment: A packet capture will tell you if your client's implementation passes GET over TLS or not ..

Comment: As long as you trust everyone who *might* have access toe the server, you're good to go! If you're concerned about how leaky the IPC of the parameters are, POST has a better track record over some channels, most particularly CGI.